# How to make transaction identifier version increment one by one in Temporal data tables in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

I was following MariaDB [System-versioning tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/temporal-data-tables/#system-versioning-tables) and doing the example as described in [transaction-precise history](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/temporal-data-tables/#transaction-precise-history-in-innodb).

Table schema was created as per the documentation,

```
CREATE TABLE t(
   x INT,
   start_trxid BIGINT UNSIGNED GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START,
   end_trxid BIGINT UNSIGNED GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END,
   PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME(start_trxid, end_trxid)
) WITH SYSTEM VERSIONING;
```

My initial table `t` has data like below.

```
+------+-------------+----------------------+
| x    | start_trxid | end_trxid            |
+------+-------------+----------------------+
|    1 |          77 | 18446744073709551615 |
|    2 |          77 | 18446744073709551615 |
|    3 |          77 | 18446744073709551615 |
+------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Then I updated `x=2` value using `UPDATE t SET x=5 WHERE x=2`. Note, I didn't specify `start_trxid` or `end_trxid`. Then all records of table were like below

```
+------+-------------+----------------------+
| x    | start_trxid | end_trxid            |
+------+-------------+----------------------+
|    1 |          77 | 18446744073709551615 |
|    5 |          84 | 18446744073709551615 |
|    3 |          77 | 18446744073709551615 |
+------+-------------+----------------------+
```

Note that, `start_trxid` changed automatically to `84` by MariaDB here.

**My Questions**:

1. How can I specify the step value for increment by 1. So, after the update, the next `start_trxid` should have been `78` instead of `84`?
2. How did MariaDB choose to have initial value to `77`. Is there any configuration to start (seed value) with `1`?

Can we really control the incrementing step here? I tried setting up `start_trxid` manually, but obviously it fails.

I tried finding any documentation regarding this but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

These are values from InnoDB transaction counter, the one that you see when you do `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`:

```
MariaDB [test]> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G
...
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 58
...

MariaDB [test]> insert into t (x) values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.091 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from t;
+------+-------------+----------------------+
| x    | start_trxid | end_trxid            |
+------+-------------+----------------------+
|    1 |          58 | 18446744073709551615 |
+------+-------------+----------------------+

MariaDB [test]> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS \G
...
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 65
...

MariaDB [test]> insert into t (x) values (2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.024 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from t;
+------+-------------+----------------------+
| x    | start_trxid | end_trxid            |
+------+-------------+----------------------+
|    1 |          58 | 18446744073709551615 |
|    2 |          65 | 18446744073709551615 |
+------+-------------+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

(Due to internal logic, even if you have only one client session, you might get not the exact value that you last saw in `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, but a bigger one).

Consequently, a user cannot configure it. It would be strange if it were possible -- to maintain the consistency of data between multiple tables, client sessions and server restarts, the counter must be global, persistent, and ever-increasing.